# Does Acquia Dev Desktop still work with Drupal 6 (upgrading sites from Drupal 6 to 7)?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I've been cheerfully using Acquia Dev Desktop for some time now, and very handy it is too, to run copies of production sites on my (iMac) workstation. I've used it for D6 and D7 sites, with the "import" option.

I've just installed the latest version of Dev Desktop and am all set to start upgrading from D6 to D7, but I keep running into problems.

1. For a start, importing a D6 site does not correctly edit the
   settings.php file (database is wrong, also $base_url does not get
   edited) - so you have to do this by hand.
2. Trying to run an upgrade
       of Views, it complains that require_once in ctools cannot find
       /usr/lib/php in /Applications/DevDesktop/pear:/common (and indeed
       when I look it is not there.

So I'm beginning to wonder whether it is still possible to use Acquia DD safely at all for running D6 sites, or upgrading from them.